# edge to edge distance between polygons that are situated within a buffer

Tags: netlogo

I would like to calculate edge to edge distance between a polygon in which is situated a turtle and each polygon that is situated in a radius of 2 km around the polygon in which is situated the turtle. The polygons are represented by different IDs and each polygon is composed of several patches. I obtain a error message with the following code "FOREACH expected this input to be a list, but got an agentset instead". I don't understand why "patches with [plabel = ID-polygon])" is not a list ? In fact, I would like to select all patches of which label is equal to label of the polygon.
Thank you for your help.

```
to-report create-edge-turtles [ID-polygon] 
let edge-turtles nobody
ask ID-polygon [ 
foreach (patches with [plabel = ID-polygon]) [
foreach sort neighbors [ 
sprout 1 [
  if [plabel] of neighbors != ID-polygon [
    face ?
    fd distance ? / 2
    set edge-turtles (turtle-set edge-turtles self)] ] ] ] ]
report edge-turtles
end code here

to-report edge-distance-between-polygons-in-buffer [indvidual]
ask individual [ 
set list-ID-polygon-in-buffer ([plabel] of patch-here in-radius 2) 
set list-ID-polygon-in-buffer remove ([plabel] of patch-here) list-ID-polygon-in-buffer 
foreach list-ID-polygon-in-buffer [ 
let ID-polygon-with-individual ([plabel] of patch-here) 
let ID-polygon-in-buffer ?  
let edges-polygon-with-individual create-edge-turtles ID-polygon-with-individual 
let edges-polygon-in-buffer create-edge-turtles ID-polygon-in_buffer 
set distance-patches min [ min [ distance myself ] of edges-polygon-in-buffer ] of edges-polygon-with-individual 
ask edges-polygon-with-individual [ die ] 
ask edges-polygon-in-buffer [ die ] ] ]
report distance-patches
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
patches with [plabel = ID-polygon]
```

returns an agentset, not a list. To turn an agentset into list simply use the `sort` keyword, as such

```
sort patches with [plabel = ID-polygon]
```